# Show certain columns in QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

Suppose I have QAbstractTableModel which feeds 2 QTableView. One tableview shows all data in the model. Please advise how can I approach to specify the other tableview to show only 2 columns from the same model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to hide the columns using the `hideColumn()` method of `QTableView`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 5, self)
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
                model.setItem(i, j, it)

        table_all = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        table_all.setModel(model)

        table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        table.setModel(model)

        for column_hidden in (0, 3, 4):
            table.hideColumn(column_hidden)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(table_all)
        lay.addWidget(table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```